# Remove empty strings from named vector in R

Tags: r, string

Does anyone know how to remove an empty string from the named vector?
I tried the following but could not get what I wanted.

```
X <- c('a', NA, '', 'b')
names(X) <- rep("d",4)
```

then I applied one the stringi function as fallow

```
stringi::stri_remove_empty(names(X)) # it return this  "a" NA  "b"
stringi::stri_remove_empty(X) # it return just the names "d" "d" "d" "d"
```

But actually I want get as following

```
 d   d   d
"a" "na" "b"
```

appreciate your help

best
adr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `nzchar` from `base R` to create a logical expression i.e. TRUE for non-blank and FALSE for blank (`""`)

```
X[nzchar(X)]
d   d   d 
"a"  NA "b"
```

If we want to remove both missing (`NA`) and blank

```
X[nzchar(X) & complete.cases(X)]
  d   d 
"a" "b"
```